# Wildcard to match string in R

Tags: r, matrix, wildcard

This might sound quite silly but it's driving me nuts.
I have a matrix that has alphanumeric values and I'm struggling to test if some elements of that matrix match only the initial and final letters. As I don't care the middle character, I'm trying (withouth success) to use a wildcard.

As an example, consider this matrix:

```
m <- matrix(nrow=3,ncol=3)
m[1,]=c("NCF","NBB","FGF")
m[2,]=c("MCF","N2B","CCD")
m[3,]=c("A3B","N4F","MCP")
```

I want to evaluate if m[2,2] starts with "N" and ends with "B", regardless of the 2nd letter in the string. I've tried something like

```
grep("N.B",m)
```

and it works, but still I want to know if there is a more compact way of doing it, like:

```
m[2,2]="N.B"
```

which ovbiously didn't work!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grepl` with the subseted `m` like:

```
grepl("^N.B$", m[2,2])
#[1] TRUE
```

or use `startsWith` and `endsWith`:

```
startsWith(m[2,2], "N") & endsWith(m[2,2], "B")
#[1] TRUE
```